# cron that needs a display

Tags: user-interface, cron

I m trying to run a cron which involves opening a graphical program and thus needs a DISPLAY set. I have tried the following:

```
*      *      *       *      *      DISPLAY=:0.0 /opt/firefox/firefox -print ..
```

It does not work and even if I try it on my console the above command does not work. It just sits there doing nothing. Now, the only way it works is the following:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0
$ crontab -l
*      *      *       *      *      DISPLAY=:10.0 /opt/firefox/firefox -print ..
```

and this works if I stay logged into the machine and wait for the cron to run.

Is there a viable way to make this work? the only way I can thin of is to always stay logged into the machine (which I want to avoid).

Comment: If you're not logged on, who's X server are you intending to display it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any simple setting to make this just work.

However, Xvfb (X Virtual Framebuffer) should be able to give you a dummy X display that should satisfy your need:

http://www.xfree86.org/4.0.1/Xvfb.1.html

Comment: It seems like the right thing to do and I did read about Xvfsb. Its  a little painful to get this running in the first place, so I just used a VncServer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do this. But if you can do this, have you then checked if the X server running when you execute this command?

Answer (score 0):

I think Nate C-K has the right idea, here is a guide on using [Xvfb and a headless Firefox](http://semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/xvfb-firefox.html). Adrian Holovaty's blog also has a discussion on a [similar need](http://www.holovaty.com/writing/headless-html-rendering-engine/) (the comments are useful).

If you just need to emulate a browser, there is always [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) and [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/).